# Mathematical software wish list

Tags: big-list, mathematical-software, software

Like many other mathematicians I use mathematical software like SAGE, GAP, Polymake, and of course $\LaTeX$ extensively. When I chat with colleagues about such software tools, very often someone has an idea of how to extend an existing tool, what (non-existent) tool would be useful, or which piece of documentation should be (re)written. Due to lack of time & energy and often also programming expertise, these ideas rarely materialize.

On the other hand, every now and then I meet programmers with a strong interest in mathematics (who are often actually trained mathematicians), and who are looking for a software project to work on. However, normally they don't really know what's needed and end up doing a non-mathematical project.

This gave me the idea to ask the mathematical community to compile a wish list for mathematical software. Wishes can be very small or or something bigger. Just try to make sure that it's realistic and maybe also give an explanation why you consider your project as interesting.

And if you happen to be a programmer fulfilling one of the wishes, please leave a comment.

It would be great if you could also include an estimate on how complex your project and what the math/coding ratio is -- but this is optional.

> ***tl;dr***
>
> - What software tool would you like to see created?
> - What existent software tool would you like to see extended by what feature?
> - What piece of documentation is missing or should be updated/extended?

One suggestion per answer, please.

Comment: It would be great to have software that serves up a website where mathematicians can ask other mathematicians questions that come up during their research.

Comment: As a programmer, I really like this question, but all of the responses so far look like they would take teams of people months to complete. :(  But I guess if it could be done by a single programmer in a week, it would already have been done, right?

Comment: My wish would be for open-source software that can plot surfaces with realistic shading.

Comment: This question is way too broad. There are some subquestions that could work, but I think you really need to restrict the scope. For example "What existent software tool would you like to see extended by what feature?" would seem to allow as answer: "I would like to see feature X in Software Y (that already  is present in Software Z)." I do not really believe it is useful to create a wishlist for the numerous differing software-packages in a single Q&A.

Comment: Likewise "What piece of documentation is missing or should be updated/extended?" solicits feedback on the documentation of a multitude of different software. Even for a single piece of software these two  questions combined seem too broad, I could see one of them for one software as a very broad question (though it is not quite clear it fits here). Anyway the scope of this Q needs to be reduced drasticaly in my opinion.

Comment: This is protected, so I can't contribute my own answer, but here goes anyway: I'd love a software that could generate (or help the user search a database of) finite difference schemes given a few constraints such as number of dimensions, desired stencil size, desired order of accuracy, particular meshes, and location on the grid (i.e. boundary points or grid points). A similar feature would be for the user to input a PDE and for the software to offer the user a few FD schemes that might work well given that problem, its geometry, etc.

Comment: @quid: While I agree that my question is fairly broad, I must admit that this is by intention. The idea is to compile a list that mathematically inclinced programmers can pick a project idea from to work on. In this regard I also find it useful to have a collection of feature requests that covers more then one software tool. If this list becomes too confusing one can still split it up into several later.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How exactly do you propose to split it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems too broad for MO to be the appropriate place

Answer (score 98):

I think some aspects of math would be revolutionized by having a good math search engine. Recently, a question was asked on Meta.MathStackExchange about what they perceived as the greatest problems facing the site. The biggest response was [that there was no search engine](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20946/9754) that indexed mathematics.

This is partly reasonable, since math is stored and documented in $\TeX$ and this can be taken as a standard. But this is also problematic, as there are multiple noncanonical ways to do things in $\TeX$. I would be remiss if I didn't say there are very many other challenging aspects of this.

As an example use case, I often have to look things up in the Gradshteyn and Ryzhik Table of Integrals and Series. It would be remarkable if there were a reasonable way to search for my expressions within the book. Even if I had to attempt multiple searches, it would almost certainly be faster. Taking it up a step, it would be great to search through TeX on the arXiv for certain expressions as well.

I think that even a relatively mediocre math search engine would be a handy start.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: A related discussion http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1564/.

Comment: I've been long interested in building such a search engine but did not get time so far, nor enough interested people who are as stoked about it. But I remain interested in it!

Comment: You might look at http://search.mathweb.org/

Comment: @RobertIsrael: good pointer; there's also a few NSF funded academic projects building math search engines with similar scopes (afaik).

Comment: Springer already have a LaTeX search - http://latexsearch.com/ - but perhaps it doesn't search everything.

Comment: @GordonRoyle: In some ancient MO thread, I remember pointing out latexsearch.com --- I have never really managed to find anything useful with it though so far!

Comment: When you say you want to search math, do you mean finding articles involving some parts of what math/text you know like: "Hey, what was that formula for ABC with a congruence relation involving $x^2$ modulo an odd power of a prime number?" Or involving a specific formula you know like: "Where did I see $\frac{a^2+b^2}{c+d}$, in reference to XYZ?" Or a specific thing like: "What's the formula for finding PQR?"

Comment: @shardulc ideally, all three. That is, I'd like a search engine that indexes both normal language and latex. In my example in GR, I was thinking along the lines of your second question about a specific formula, which is (as far as I know) not at all an available service.

Comment: This is actually a problem I'm facing. How best to index theorems, how to uniquely express something (say an integral) under some rules that leave the result unique, so forth.

Comment: You might consider something like this (http://mathlex.org/demo) which can record the semantic meaning while still displaying LaTeX as a starting point.

Comment: There's also http://functions.wolfram.com/

Comment: A review of some current math search engines have been uploaded to arXiv recently: https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.03457

Comment: If one had a search engine which indexes all theorems/lemmas/... in all articles and which allows to search for (assumptions) with (conclusions).

Comment: There exists [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/), which is a search engine currently only for MSE. I believe it to be some 2 years old, and its author has polished it in the meantime. I myself have been quite impressed by what it can do. Yes, it is LaTeX-aware.

Comment: This is a hard problem. To build an _effective_ search engine you'd have to visually parse the equations from PDFs or the visual rendering of HTML/TeX, similar to [handwritten equation analysis](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~rlaz/files/LeiHuPhDDissertation_May2016.pdf). Not sure the state of that technology. Then once you get the equations parsed, finding equivalencies based on some standard definition, which would require a formalization of mathematics such as in HoTT with Coq. Then figuring out what actually needs to be searched for from a UX perspective.

Comment: @lancejpollard [MathPix](https://mathpix.com/), a OCR made for LaTeX, seems to be working very well.

Answer (score 53):

A more modern typesetting language to replace $\TeX$. TeX is basically impossible to parse and its internals are really odd and difficult to work with, when one tries to do something advanced.

Knuth is a genius, and it was a really neat hack for the time, but, with all due respect, after 30 years of experience with computer typesetting I am sure it is possible to put together something better.

If not, at least a TeX compiler with better error messages.

Comment: TeX is certainly not a "neat hack".

Comment: Please not. TeX is perfect as it is. The change of format of mathematical papers is undesirable.

Comment: Tex was and is an extraordinary achievement, and is fantastic for what it is, and almost certainly superior to the alternatives, but (like any long-lived project) it has acquired a huge accumulation of cruft, much of which is rather dated.  So if a dedicated team led by a clone of Knuth could write a new system, from the ground up, following the same principles as TeX and learning from what TeX’s many contributors have done in the mean time — I suspect we could end up with a significantly better system still.  But there’s probably too much intertia for this to happen any time soon.

Comment: Isn't exactly this done by the developers of systems like Context, LuaTeX, ... ?

Comment: I'll just leave a link here: http://latex-project.org/latex3.html

Comment: @JohannesHahn As far as I understand, Context is a macro system alternative to LaTeX, so it builds upon TeX but uses the same underlying engine and syntax. Luatex is, in my view, a very promising project: it is still TeX, but aims to support modifying all of the document properties with scripting, a bit like DOM+Javascript for HTML.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine TeX is certainly not fantastic for what it is.  If it is superior to its alternatives, it's because there are no alternatives.  A new system could still have implementations of LaTeX and TeX commands so that current LaTeX packages and old TeX/LaTeX source files remain usable.

Comment: While a better system does exist in the platonic realm, given the bug-free monolothic design of TeX any **realistic change** is extremely likely to be for the worse, for there are essentially no known examples of big software that do not suffer from bugs, design-by-committee, backward- and forward-incompatibilities, poor manuals, etc. *Better is enemy of good*.

Comment: @juan TeX is not perfect as is. Among the desirable properties of TeX would be a format that is easier to parse. The highest rated answer at this moment is a search engine for maths, and this is precisely the type of things that are currently very difficult just because the format has lots of quirks. A different document format may make a search engine a much easier task

Comment: There is a lot of work being done to make LaTeX more accessible through online services such as [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) and [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com) (disclaimer - I'm one of the [founders of Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/about)), and these are specifically looking to combine the benefits of the fantastic typesetting engine with a modern (and collaborative) interface.

Comment: Many of the answers to OP's question seem to be about TeX or the related family of software.  If you want to support the development of this family, or indeed just support the continued existence of versions of the software runnable on current platforms, please consider joining the people who are making that happen.  Join, or donate to, a [TeX Users Group](http://www.tug.org) (disclaimer: I am VP of TUG).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni AFAIK modern ConTeXt heavily relies on the LuaTeX engine and (but I may be mistaken) LuaTeX and ConTeXt development in a sense are going hand in hand.

Comment: Yes the_fox you right and polite: a mathematician is neither a secretary nor a typographer. Yet he has to make up with each drudgery. Knuth is precise but does not understand the functional point of view. My taxes should be used to develop latex as a tool for maths and many disciplines, instead of being given to dubious publishers asking us to pay for articles written by researchers subsided by my very taxes (from an angry programmer).

Comment: TeX is good to very good as is. The problem, however, is the use of cookbook straitjacket time-varying LaTeX, and this by about 99% of users. Learning plain TeX forces you to be able to learn enough to solve TeX problems for yourself.

Comment: What whould you improve in LaTeX and how would you like to make it better?

Comment: @TKe For instance, just listing things on the top of my head (1) a more modern syntax with a proper parser (2) an easier programming interface and access to internals (Luatex partially solves this) (3) better error messages (4) a debugger (5) ability to interface with other programming languages (`\write18` does not really count) (6) IEEE arithmetic.

Comment: @ FedericoPoloni Your are right an interface and  well documented libraryies Here is a problem how do I define circled symbols such as union , intersection , start etc.. With a guaranty of proper scaling. I thing it is hard to produce and I could no find it  in existing libraries: showing how little orthogonality there is so far. The argument often heard in favor of Tex is how useful it is which is true ONLY because we have nothing else.   Writing with a quill is nice for a while only : it look as if  people are deriving a pervert pleasure wallowing  inside low level syntax.

Comment: I agree, that's why we have $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 35):

I always thought it would be nice to have a real-time virtual blackboard (supporting digitizer pen), say, as an extension of Skype or similar service, where you can not only talk with a colleague but also do math together over great distances.

Comment: I think there are already several services offering this -- see for instance http://www.webdistortion.com/2011/01/22/best-online-collaborative-drawing-tools/.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am getting "page not found" from your link.

Comment: @July Try with this link: http://www.webdistortion.com/2011/01/22/best-online-collaborative-drawing-tools/

Comment: Have you tried searching for this at all?  There's a **TON** of [collaborative whiteboard solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=collaborative+whiteboard) out there already, many of which have Skype extensions.  First few results from Google: https://ziteboard.com/   http://www.groupboard.com/products/  https://syncpadapp.com/  https://idroo.com/home  https://realtimeboard.com/  http://www.twiddla.com/  https://www.scribblar.com/  https://awwapp.com/

Comment: There's also [hack.chat](https://hack.chat), which is text chat that allows you to input LaTeX expressions also.

Comment: Related: [Tools for long-distance collaboration](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49384/tools-for-long-distance-collaboration). (And maybe also some other links listed in the comments [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/chatting-about-mathematics-with-real-time-latex-rendering#comment192307_81365)).

Comment: @BlueRaja: I have searched, and most of them are not particularly good. Instead of naming everything google shows, it would be more helpful to point to a particular piece of software that is proved to work well.

Comment: The tool MathCAD can be good. It is designed as a maths white board for engineers, and has the patents. Unfortunately it is now part of the much larger corporate PTC who do regular CAD tools, so it is being diverted off to supporting certified drawings. It also embeds a CAS engine.

Answer (score 32):

A vastly improved support for handwritten math (e.g. via digitizer pen) incl. its conversion to typeset math would be awesome! In a long run, ideally it should be able to replace LaTeX. Just think of how much of researchers' time is spent on inputting math.

Comment: One existing tool in this direction is [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), which can recognize handwritten symbols and tell the TeX code. This is often much faster than consulting [a symbol list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). Maybe the Detexify project could help build the required math recognition software?

Comment: I agree, it is a start. But I think it will take some years before we get a complete solution. Recognizing 'normal' handwriting properly is already a difficult problem (but it has improved a lot over the past few years, especially with handheld devices and 'apps' and such). And then, on top of it, one has the whole particularity of the mathematical notation.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Detexify's recognition is not so great, though the idea is.  About half the time I try to use it, I give up and do a web search or consult a symbol list.

Comment: Neural nets have made decent strides towards reliably recognizing handwritten letters. Have they been used for recognizing math symbols yet?

Comment: http://www.wiris.com/ has a big step in this direction.

Comment: Another one: http://myscript.com/technology/technical-demonstrations/

Comment: I doubt that handwriting math and then digitalizing it is much faster than writing it in TeX.

Answer (score 27):

**An improved version of [latexdiff](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff)**

A good diff software is essential for collaboratively writing articles. Latexdiff takes two tex files and outputs a new tex file with the differences highlighted (additions are underlined in blue and deletions are crossed out in red). This is very useful since it facilitates viewing the changes that coauthors have made during a round of editing, especially if some of your coauthors are not super computer-savy (e.g., they don't use diff themselves) since you can just pass them the output PDF with the marked changes.

However, my experience with using latexdiff is that the output file usually requires some manual editing before it can be compiled into a PDF, since the diff markup algorithm often messes up the latex syntax. It would be useful to have a more user-friendly latexdiff.

Comment: The online TeX Editor Sharelatex has a history feature that sounds a lot like what you are asking for. This of course helps only if all collaborators use this editor and it is only available if you pay a monthly fee or manage to recruit enough participants.

Answer (score 21):

I would like software that makes the specific job of managing mathematical references easier.

When I've looked, there are BibTeX and its relatives for making sure that the whole process stays under control; many tools for managing references; tools for pulling BibTeX from MathSciNet; tools for creating BibTeX from arxiv identifiers; tools for searching these places for papers; tools for merging BibTeX files; and so on.

Using these individually simplifies individual parts of the process. But I always find that I need to:

- copy my bibliography from my previous paper, and maybe another one,
- merge in some more bibliography entries from my other previous paper where my coauthor managed the file, and eliminate the duplicates and inconsistencies,
- try to figure out which papers have moved from preprints to arXiv preprints to being published, and update their entries,
- go through new published references I'm adding, hunt them down, and copy-paste BibTeX from MathSciNet,
- create new entries for the arXiv preprints,
- and then some misc. extra jobs that always show up, like fixing tildes and putting capitals in braces and adding hyperlinks to bib entries that lack them because they date all the way back to my thesis.

The process is exhausting and the tools don't click together enough to make it much easier - e.g. automating pulling references from MathSciNet seems almost not worth the trouble because it involves firing up special-purpose software that's only useful for half of the new entries that I'm referencing.

Comment: I haven't really used it much but the postdocs at my last lab used https://www.mendeley.com/ to organize the papers they've read. You can export BibTeX from it, too.

Comment: We mathematicians are already extremely lucky to have MathSciNet. As far as I know, in most other fields there is basically no publication database that can produce Bibtex entries of reasonable quality (names in the correct format, capitals properly escaped, consistent journal names).

Comment: There is [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org). It is not without problems (multilingual search could be better, BibTeX export is very mediocre), but in my experience it has been the best among available software.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni We are doubly-lucky: we have not only MathSciNet, but also Zentralblatt. It has an advantage over MathSciNet that the first three search results are free (require no subscription) --- many here are in sufficiently wealthy institutions that this does not matter, but for some it is valuable.

Comment: Astronomy is also lucky has ADS. Which now covers a good bit of physics and some other sciences as well, afaik.

Comment: DBLP now indexes most of theoretical computer science and, unlike MathSciNet, is free to use.

Comment: I use JabRef and get the bibtex entries from Mathscinet, Zentralblatt, or google books.  If you keep a folder with the articles in pdf you can open them directly from JabRef.   It still requires some discipline and I find it hard to avoid developing several "branches" of my database.

Comment: There are several emacs packages that allow importing bibtex entries from arxiv, mathscinet, etc. without leaving the editor. Most of the other problems are solved by using Mathscinet bibtex entries (including the citation keys!) whenever possible and using a single bib database for all your writing.

Comment: @BorisBukh: the [MR lookup](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mrlookup) feature of MathSciNet also gives three results and requires no subscription. It is unfortunately a bit literal, so it won't find anything if you make a typo.

Answer (score 20):

I find it particularly cumbersome to produce good-looking mathematical illustrations. I know of several ways to make decent cartoon images in bitmap format with little hassle, but I prefer the image quality provided by vector graphics. TikZ seems to be the go-to for math-based vector graphics, but this is incredibly time consuming, even after climbing the learning curve.

**I would very much like a bmp-to-tikz "converter."**

Depending on the quality of the bitmap, the converter might need to iteratively suggest a vector-graphics interpretation for the user to evaluate. The user could then fine tune the TikZ code after conversion if he's extremely picky.

Comment: Or maybe an xfig-like visual editor for tikz?

Comment: @Kimball Inkscape has an extension to export to tikz.

Comment: Inkscape also has a feature to turn bmp to svg (e.g. by color) and then you can use the svg to tikz feature.

Comment: Here is an example of bmp to TikZ way via `potrace`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172336/drawing-roman-laurel-leaves-spqr-in-tikz

Comment: Even though it costs money, for some illustrations Omnigraffle is pretty nice! There's also an MO thread on tools for mathematical illustration (for quick drawing IPE is also quite good, but not easy to get fine grained enough)...

Comment: Sounds rather like a beefburger to cow converter :-/

Comment: I don't really see the usefulness here. If you can make a decent cartoon images in bitmap format, you might as well make vector images (e.g. using Inkscape; if you really want, you can even convert bitmaps to vector graphics, though that won't look good). And why would you use tikz instead of plain pdf/eps/svg (except when you want tighter control over the generated image - and converting from bitmaps won't give you that).

Answer (score 19):

LaTeX support (or mode) in voice-recognition softwares for people with upper limb disabilities.
Maybe via Dragon NaturallySpeaking or something new entirely.
Something similar for coding as well!

Comment: coding with Dragon + custom scripts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SkdfdXWYaI

Comment: Didn't Stephen Hawking write something about how he did this in his autobiography?

Answer (score 16):

It would be nice to have a pdf viewer which gave the user the option to collapse and also restore individual proof sections.

Comment: I think this can be better achieved by moving away from PDFs to something like XHTML.

Comment: Philipp Kühls PhD Thesis is about algebraic surgery. However for fun he also coded his own pdf viewer with features very similar to what you are asking for. www.surgery-hotel.de

Answer (score 15):

**A wiki-like mathematical structure/example data base**

I can imagine this better as an online service than a locally running software, but nevertheless I imagine it to be very useful.

> You ever wondered (because of your research or out of curiosity) whether there is an example of a structure A (e.g. a topological space, graph, group, ...) which has the properties B, C and D, but not E? If *Yes*, what is an example of such a structure? If *No*, how can this be proven?

Wouldn't it be nice to have an online service, something like Wikipedia, where you can enter that you are browsing the database of structures A, and you specify the filters [B], [C], [D] and [not E]. You press enter and it spits out:

- Here is an example of such a structure: ...
- These structures are exactly the 3-dimensional compact manifolds. An example would be: ...
- No structure can have this combination of properties. Source: ...
- It is conjectured that no such structure exists. Source: ...
- It is a known open problem whether there is such a structure: Read more here: ...
- Property [B] and [C] imply [D] and [not E]. Hence you are actually looking for structures A with only [D] and [not E].
- The database does not contain information on this combination of properties. Do you want to extend the knowledge?

"wiki-like" means that the database's knowledge can be extended/corrected by anyone $-$ like in Wikipedia. Even though this might seem like a complicated semantic search engine, I think that the strong formalization we have in mathmatics enables us to choose a strict syntax for the input.

- We always specify the general structure we are looking for, e.g. vector space, topological space, metric space, group, ring, field, graph, function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, subset of $\Bbb R$, curve (in metric space), field-automorphism, ...
- It follows a list of properties, e.g. finite, compact, 3-dimensional, connected, Hausdorff, has inner point, metrizable, bijective, ... . Every such property can be suffixed with a [not]-operator. The listed properties are joined by conjunction.

The structures and property names are no free-form input, but chosen from a pop-up menu or by auto-completion, so that the users know what to input. The database should implement very basic reasoning, e.g.

- If a property A implies B, and B implies C, so does A imply C.
- If A and B contradict each other and C implies A, so C and B contradict each other too.
- The structures can be linked, e.g. every metric space is a topological space (by its induced topology). Hence, every property which is available for topological spaces, is also available for metric spaces.

I know of several such services of varying generality: e.g. for [rings](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/), groups, graphs ([here](https://hog.grinvin.org/) and [here](http://www.graphclasses.org/)), polyhedra, or general [counterexamples](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/). The differences to what I am looking for can mostly be described by the following points:

- General: I want a combined database for all/most structures. All this under a common interface.
- Extendable: I think everyone should be allowed to add his knowledge to the database.
- Searchable: Most of the time I know only the names (or some names or vague descriptions) of some properties of the desired structure. I do not know the structures name. Hence I want to filter by these properties. Sometimes I might be not even interested in examples, but in the relation between two properties: e.g. do they contradict each other, are they the same, does one imply the other, ...?
- Structured: Not a loose collection of examples/counterexamples/articles, but highly interconnected and analysable data.
- Userfriendly/Beautiful: I think [mathcounterexamples](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/) and of course StackExchange is a good demonstration of these goals.

I once had an idea how this can be realized. I even asked a [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77767/datastructure-for-managing-abstract-sets) on Computer Science StackExchange to see whether useful data structure for this kind of task already exist. I would love to realize such a project, but I am definitely lacking the web-developer skills, and currently also the time.

Comment: There is also [Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/) among the "things which aren't quite what you're asking for but are at least somewhat in the right direction". But the whole thing should be part of a larger "semantic web" effort: Wikimedia made a step in this direction by creating [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page) which should, ultimately, make it possible to query Wikipedia-and-sisters in semantically useful ways (like "give me a list of French painters born between 1800 and 1835"), so maybe if this takes off, math can benefit from the infrastructure.

Answer (score 12):

There should be $\LaTeX$-browsers. The (relatively) new HTML 5 is great. It'd be still wonderful to have both: HTML-browsers (as today) and $\LaTeX$-browsers.

Comment: What is a LaTeX browser?

Comment: What is an HTML browser?

Comment: A program that takes HTML as an input and display on the screen formatted text. So, according to my definition, `pdflatex` + any pdf reader of your choice is a LaTeX browser. That's why I asked for your definition, not for a counter-question.

Comment: how about http://www.sharelatex.com ?  "LATEX-browser" inside your "HTML browser" =)

Comment: When you enter url like abc.HTML in an browser then you see the html-formatted text. *** When you enter url like abc.tex in a latex browser than you see the latex-formatted file.

Comment: [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) is often used for this - it combines an online LaTeX editor with a [rich-text mode](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/81) to help authors new to LaTeX and those experienced users in collaboration with non-LaTeX users. You can then share your work easily via the browser. (Note - I'm one of the [founders of Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/about), and if you use it, feedback is always appreciated, thanks).

Comment: Like [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/)? Not a browser per se but nearly there.

Comment: This could be accomplished as a browser extension.

Comment: There's no real point in doing a whole browser for this. Just use a plugin or a dedicated website to compile LaTeX source code to an output format on the spot.

Comment: This exist in the form of MathML (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML)

Comment: @JIXiang yeah this is too specific of a technology to have a browser dedicated to it, don't see that happening. Better math support in JavaScript components would be along these lines. Getting GitHub to support math in Markdown would be a step in this direction. https://github.com/github/markup/issues/897

Answer (score 11):

[In short, a place we can find a more modern proof, or a proof with a different approach, than the original paper that is customary to cite.]

One of the comments mentioned moving LaTeX from PDF to an XHTML sort of environment (Stacks Project is a good example). It may be worth expanding on that as a separate answer.

One obvious advantage is that words in text mode can be searched. And it may be a step towards making LaTeX code searchable (the current top answer). Most of the non-mathematical TeX codes (bullet points, *italic*, include pictures) we can use markdown like here on MathOverflow.

But the real game-changer is to **make it more like GitHub**, where one can **fork** a proof in order to add missing details, or make more substantial rewriting, and "publish" it for all to see. The rest of us can vote on them. Eventually the platform should have sufficiently many of the basic theorems (with many different proofs) in all branches of mathematics that we can cite directly, instead of citing the original paper or a textbook. The citations can also be used to generate a "dependency graph", barring circular reasonings (It may not be as exhaustive in the details as in Stacks Project, or we'd lose the big pictures).

If we want to say a certain result (say, in a certain abstract theory) is important, we can just point to it and see how many important results—or results that *you* care about—are connected to it. It may be more fun to learn new mathematics this way, combining the best of all textbooks, old and new.

Aside from the theorems, there would be special pages that are more expository, giving historical context (say of a problem) and connecting different theorems into a coherent narrative without getting bogged down in the details of proofs.

Now, wouldn't that be the new publishing model that we have all wished for? Credit may be traced from the forking history. (Of course if we are 
"importing" or rewriting a proof in the literature we should give proper citations.)

Comment: You might want to check out openmathematics.org, which doens't have GitHub support for files and comments yet, but soon will have.

Comment: I think the Stack Project just made their underlying system available, called Gerby https://github.com/gerby-project/gerby-project.github.io/blob/master/index.md They are now working with Jacob Lurie's (yet to unveil) project Kerodon.

This is still a single narrative type of math writing.

Comment: This is very interesting! Do you know anything more about Kerodon? Googling quickly, I see that he's gotten the logo sorted, but not much else is visible.

Comment: Also, I see you have started your own project. Can you go into some more detail about what you hope to do with it?

Comment: @JamesSmith, sorry I don't know anything about Kerodon. (I don't have the time or means to make my own project; I'm just trying out what others have set up. I used brilliant.org for a bit, but their active user base is too elementary. Now I use observablehq, which is for coding/data analysis/visualization. I think it has great potential, even as a model for some scientific publishing but perhaps not for math.)

Comment: No worries about Kerodon. I'll keep a look out for it. The Observable stuff looks interesting, too. But I agree, probably not for maths. Although they list KaTeX as a dependency so I suppose you can do some maths with it.

Answer (score 9):

What I think would be most useful to address this issue is improving the system to make requests and contributions to such software packages.  I'm sure many of these systems would be happy to have more help with development.

For instance, I found that the Sage implementation of computation of zeta functions of graphs is horribly slow and I wrote a much faster implementation (using Sage), and I wanted give Sage my code so they could use it a subsequent release, but after looking at the amount of effort required to contribute code, I decided I didn't want to spend that much time on it.  I was just hoping to submit my code with some comments, which an interested developer could revise to conform to standards, test and implement.

One example of something I would like implemented (say in Sage) is computation of $p$-adic integrals.  E.g., given a compact open subgroup $K$ of $GL_2(\mathbb Q_p)$ and a character $\psi$ on the upper unipotent $N$, compute $\int_N 1_K(n) \psi(n) \, dn$. (Some simple cases like basic character sums might be implemented, but possibly they are only implemented mod $p$.)  I once thought about trying to automate calculations for a highly computational project I had, but then decided it wasn't worth the development time for just that one project.

Comment: William Stein was so put off by the Sage contribution standards, that he forked purplesage (psage) to be his own sandbox, with lower conformity.

Comment: Do you refer to the Ihara zeta function ? You should at least have proposed your code to Sage, as this is rather easy.

Comment: @F.C. Yes.  Can you tell me how to do this?  I had read [this](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/faq/faq-contribute.html), which seems to require more than 10 minutes of effort.

Comment: 1) get an account on trac.sagemath.org 2) open a ticket 3) attach your code to that ticket. Of course, this means that the real work is left to somebody else than you.

Comment: Code Standards are different from maintainer to maintainer, but as a professional software developer, I will tell you they absolutely exist for a reason.  Relaxing code standards across the board purely for the sake of making it easier for amateur developers to make contributions would result in your software having more bugs than features.

Comment: @nhgrif I also believe in coding standards.  I am just saying I would like the contribution system be improved to make it easier for mathematicians to contribute (which possibly includes a level of vetting by developers).  Maybe already the system for this is good, but this wasn't clear from the documentation, so perhaps the documentation on this should at least be made more friendly for well-meaning but busy/lazy laymen.

Comment: @Kimball: contributing to Sage is very easy. I highly recommend writing an email to sage-trac-account AT googlegroups DOT com as suggested on the [trac page](http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac) with your email id and a username of your choice!

Comment: Hi -- purple sage didn't work due to lack of time.    Regarding dumping useful code on us, that we have to understand and get up to snuff for inclusion, if we had more time and bandwidth, then we would make that easy.  However, we don't -- I have almost not grant support, and almost all effort is researchers in their spare time.  Maybe if we someday have funding...

Comment: From a Sage embarrassingly-non-expert:  is it really true that the *creator* of Sage was so frustrated by contributing code to *his own project* that he had to make a private fork?

Comment: @LSpice Obviously we should let William Stein comment himself, but my reading of the situation was that at the time (2010-ish), Sage had established enough momentum that it's future was assured, so he (Stein) could focus primarily on (software for) his own research area.

Answer (score 9):

For the sake of searching mathematical texts one could create a purely auxiliary language sTeX, a simplified $\LaTeX$ -- just a software tool (not directly for people). Then one would add a "translator" (or rather a *simplifier*) from $\LaTeX$ into sTeX. Then search engines (like Google) can search texts in $\LaTeX$ by first obtaining the intermediate sTeX.

Mathematicians may learn just a little bit about sTeX to make mathematical searches still more efficient (but even without knowing anything about sTeX, the mathematical searches will be much easier to handle than without sTeX anyway).

Comment: It would have to be called something else, though:  http://ctan.org/pkg/stex .  Also, it seems like the mathematical (La)TeX understood by MathOverflow's flavour of Markdown is already a pretty bare-bones version.

Answer (score 8):

A blog comment hosting service that supports *MathJax in comments*.

Currently most of the services uses iframes, making comments with MathJax impossible to render (unless the service provides native support for MathJax.)

Comment: I understand that you are suggesting an externally-hosted comment system, but WordPress comments could likely be MathJax-enabled with little effort. This doesn't help with services like Medium or other blog hosting services, though.

Answer (score 7):

Another thing I would like to see (not strictly math only) is a proper editor for .djvu (for all platforms) documents the way there are such editors for .pdf documents. Especially for bigger scanned documents (like many historical stuff in math), .djvu offers much better compression and much smoother viewing performance. To my knowledge, there is only one program that comes close to a .djvu *editor*, but unfortunately it is lacking in many regards.

On a related note, it would be nice to have a proper .pdf editor, native for Linux (there is one that comes close to the Windows ones, but it is not developed and has many problems, including usability ones), so that one does not need to use (the somewhat unstable) wine.

Comment: In terms of PDF editors, would QPDF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QPDF) or iText (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IText) provide any of the desired functionality?

Comment: Agree. It is a shame there is still no free and professional tool to at least highlight and comment pdf, and save/print the changes. The best I could find is Xournal that simply converts pdfs to images.

Comment: Regarding your second request, I'd like to mention "Master PDF Editor" (https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor).

Comment: Thanks, but I've used Master PDF Editor before. It used to be a bit slow and buggy and the gui was suboptimal. Maybe that has changed by now. I have not tried @LSpice 's suggestions yet, but I will soon (when I am again in Linux).

Comment: What is the one program that comes close to being a DjVu editor?

Comment: @LSpice: It is called Document Express Desktop from Cuminas, it includes Document Express DjVu Editor among other things like .djvu printer and shell extensions. It's not free, but they offer a trial. The shell extensions can be had separately and free of charge IIRC.

Answer (score 7):

It would be great if mathematical plotting programs like gnuplot would support both mouse based zoom-in and mouse based zoom-out. I once tried to describe what I mean in a German post titled [Zoom-out could be so easy](http://jakitoimgeisterhaus.blogspot.de/2014/10/verkleinern-konnte-so-einfach-sein.html), but the description is too incomplete. One issue of that post is that you normally want to keep the aspect ratio. And the concrete formulas are also missing. Both issues could be solved easily, but the principal issue that people don't understand why this would be important is much harder to address.

Comment: To try to put in one sentence what Thomas wants, for non-readers of German: just as many programs allow one to zoom in by drawing a rectangle in the current viewport over the part one wants to zoom in on, one should be able to zoom out by drawing a rectangle to show which part of viewport should contain the current image.

Comment: Isn't this more or less pinch-to-zoom as found on touchscreens? Just for the special case where the starting points of the two fingers are two corners of the viewport.

Comment: @Max Probably yes. But the most important point is that the touchscreens have a well working zoom-in and zoom-out. For some strange reasons, programs like gnuplot (and matlab) do have well working zoom-in, but miss well working zoom-out.

Comment: Have you looked into interactive plotting tools like Bokeh? It's a Python library, but there are ports to a few other languages.

Answer (score 7):

Idea generator using generative machine learning. If it can generate new art, lets give it a try with math.

[image]

Using new techniques from machine learning's aspect of generating new data (eg. GAN networks), it would be very interesting to devise algorithms that input massive amounts of theorems and problems and combine them in various ways to output new statements.

- As in supervised machine learning, the human will be labeling whether the output was helpful in giving them novel perspectives.
- A first step in the algorithm would be rephrasing the theorem's and problem's statements in as many different ways as possible. Often big bridges in math are build because we managed to find equivalent problems from distinct areas that allowed an exchange of techniques.

Related:

- [Is there research on Machine Learning techniques to discover conjectures (theorems) in a wide range of mathematics beyond mathematical logic?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231583/is-there-research-on-machine-learning-techniques-to-discover-conjectures-theore)
- [Interesting conjectures "discovered" by computers and proved by humans?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92148/interesting-conjectures-discovered-by-computers-and-proved-by-humans)

Comment: Since GANs shown remarkable success on images inputs, I wonder if this project could be used to have new applications in the field: https://mathpicture.fas.harvard.edu/

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to have on a usb key a user friendly software that could parse a math article to check the proofs in it without having to learn how to use stuff like Coq and highlight the possible gaps. But this may sound unrealistic, at least for now.

Comment: If a computer could parse an English document and understand if something could be possibly formalized as a proof, it would be half-way to being a mathematician itself.

Comment: Indeed, the question itself is sort of like: "What can make my life as a mathematician easier, but without obsoleting me?"

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily replace the creative process that is essential to research.

Comment: Well anyway, this would be *extremely difficult*. It won't be like some programmer is looking for something to do and he says "oh, let me just create a skynet to check Sylvain Julien's articles for errors."

Comment: Don't worry, there's no need of Skynet for this :-)

Comment: It's very likely that this *would* necessarily be almost as creative as a mathematician. Note how difficult it is to train humans to do this task: almost all of them who we successfully train to being able to assess math articles, also reach the epsilon-higher level of being able to generate some.

Comment: Yeah, this is as "AI Complete" as it gets. In other words, if you build this thing, you should build a couple other multi-billion dollar industries around it.

Comment: To me, this problem has more or less the same flavor as P vs NP. If you consider that checking the proof of any given theorem is as easy as finding a proof thereof, this would mean that checking a solution of a (NP complete? NP difficult?) problem (prove any given theorem) is as easy as finding it. I'm by no means expert in complexity theory, but your position sounds unlikely to me.

Comment: Ganesalingam and Barnet-Lamb [were working on this](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/mg262/); I'm not sure whether they still are.

Answer (score 3):

The website

[swmath.org](http://www.swmath.org/)

helps in finding existing mathematical software and documentation.

From their website:

> **What is swMATH?**
>
> swMATH is a freely accessible, innovative information service for
>   mathematical software. swMATH not only provides access to an extensive
>   database of information on mathematical software, but also includes a
>   systematic linking of software packages with relevant mathematical
>   publications.
>
> The intention is to offer a list of all publications that refer to a
>   software recorded in swMATH. In particular, all articles are given,
>   which are included in Zentralblatt MATH (zbMATH). It can be both,
>   articles that describe the background and technical details of a
>   program, as well as those publications in which a piece of software is
>   applied or used for research.
>
> In this way, swMATH provides information on actual use of the software
>   that is otherwise impossible or very difficult to obtain. At the same
>   time the documentation of literature referring to a software is a
>   valuable source of information for the authors of the software about
>   where their software is used. Moreover, if software is cited in
>   scientific publications, this is also an important quality criterion,
>   which is used by swMATH for software selection.
>
> swMATH sees itself as a service to the mathematical community.
>   Additions, corrections and other notes from authors and users of
>   mathematical software can be communicated under 'Feedback' and are
>   very welcome.
>
> For more detailed information, we refer to the following [article](http://www.swmath.org/media/documents/swMATH.pdf).

[...]

> **Project Information**
>
> swMATH is a project of the Mathematical Research Institute Oberwolfach
>   (MFO) and FIZ Karlsruhe (FIZ), funded by the Leibniz Association
>   2011-2013.
>
> Project leader: Gert-Martin Greuel (MFO); Wolfram Sperber (FIZ)
>   Concept, programming, design: Michael Brickenstein, Christoph Knoth
>   (MFO); Sebastian Bönisch, Hagen Chrapary (FIZ)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to have a feature in a (La)TeX IDE that would allow one to ``collapse" one's document tree into a single file.   I modularize my typesetting: I have separate files for definitions, lemmas, \newcommands, etc., and it is not convenient to share all of the separate files with others.

Uploading one's document tree to the arXiv--one file at a time--is a tedious chore.  Also,  some editors request that submissions be put into a single file for publication.   The ability to work modularly and then readily convert the corpus to a single file would be useful.

Comment: Regarding the upload of files one by one: there's the [bundledoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc?lang=en) tool, which can automatically make a `.tar.gz` which is ready to be be uploaded to arXiv (tested it myself). About the "collapsing" of files, the closest thing is probably [latexpand](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexpand?lang=en), a Perl script which puts all your `\include`s and `\input`s into a single TeX file. If you're on Debian-based Linux, both tools are available in the package `texlive-extra-utils`.